# Can I localize app store metadata for more than the supported languages?

Tags: ios-appstore, language

I need to localize an app to fit markets which are actually not in the list of markets supported in the iTunes App Store (see [here](https://gist.github.com/nuthatch/8543415)). So e.g. if you want to customize your app description for the Romanian market you would have to incorporate Romanian specialties in the English (GB) version of your app metadata. If you have to support a multitude of markets this can become very unpleasant. Also it's not convenient for Romanian people that they have to look at english descriptions (although the manufacture would have loved to translate it to Romanian).

Is there a way to overcome this situation by any means?